# Google reCaptcha v2 test with Postman

Tags: wordpress, post, postman, contact-form, invisible-recaptcha

I am a manual tester on a project, the Project is a company website, there was a need to test contact forms using POST requests in Postman.

**Task:** the site uses invisible Google recaptcha. We need to test (on the Prod server): that the sent contact forms are successfully delivered to the mailbox. So we need to pass/bypass the captcha for this check.

**Problem:** unfortunately, I don't know any of the programming languages yet, and I can't use the existing solutions in this problem. Therefore, the attempt to create valid queries failed.

**Questions:**
1- Does this problem have a solution? Is it possible to pass captcha requests and send contact forms on the Site. If the answer is "Yes", then what is needed for this.
2- Could someone point me in the direction of solving this problem. What is worth reading, what solutions to this problem exist?

I will be grateful for any tips, then I will discuss it in more detail with our development team. Thank you !!